# What is the correct file extension for Orange image embedding?

Tags: orange

I am using Orange data mining in order to create a facial recognition workflow with some prototype widgets. To do this, I am trying to import some images (test data) using the import widget.

My question is: which file format do I need to use in order for the image data to be compatible with the import widget? In other words, which file format should I use to upload the image?

I have tried using JPEG but when I click "browse for images" to search for images on my desktop, it doesn't allow me to select anything to import.

Does this imply that it is not compatible? Is there a specific file format that I should be using in order to do the image detection/embedding process?

Comment: Maybe an xml file is needed.

Comment: When I try this, I select a folder, not individual images. For me, jpeg then works...

Answer (score 2):

As r.kfr said: Import Images works with folders, not individual images. Place all images in a folder and select it for import.
Note that if you have images in different folders, Orange will consider each folder name as a class label for images.

Alternatively, you can create an Excel/CSV file and define the path to the image. Mark it with *meta type=image* in the third header row. Here is how to define the [header](http://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/loading-your-data/index.html#header-with-attribute-type-information).

Answer (score 1):

First add the File widget, then create a xls file with 2 columns:

1. name of image
2. image path

Orange will import the images by itself.